# Is there a way to override or skip calling a parent's constructor?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, constructor

Is there a way to override or skip calling a **parent's constructor**? For example, I have the following:

```
contract Ape {
  constructor() {
    // Initialise some stuff in Ape constructor
  }
}

contract Human is Ape {
  constructor() {
    // Initialise some stuff WITHOUT running whatever that is in Ape.constructor
  }
}
```

> Currently, I notice that the parent constructor will **always be called**. In my case, I'm creating mock contract which inherits a target contract for `testing` and I don't want anything in the parent contract's constructor to be initialized so that I can test things out.

Is there any way in some languages where the parent constructor will be only called by `super()`?

> In my case, I would like to omit `super()` so nothing in the parent constructor is called.

Comment: you can't just remove the constructor from your parent contract?

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa I can't remove the parent constructor. I'm just trying to extend it into a mock contract for testing. The parent constructor is still needed in actual usage but the initialisation in it is preventing me from testing and that's why I wanted my mock to not run the constructor in its parent.

Comment: I have never encountered this situation. But knowing that if it was possible, variables would be there, but with the default value.
Namely, 0 for `uint`, "" for `string`, false for `bool`, address(0) for `address`, etc.
So you could initialize them with their default values to reproduce the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this statement for only test because is 'craftmanship' solution.
Check this example contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Parent {
  string _test = "Empty";

  constructor(bool checkInit) {
    if(checkInit)
        init();
  }

  function init() internal {
      _test = "Hello World / Father";
  }
  
}

contract Child is Parent {
  constructor() Parent(true) {
    
  }

  function getName() external view returns(string memory) {
      return _test;
  }
}
```

I put a boolean into a father constructor and if this boolean is true then the smart contract call the `init()` method. This functions contains the initializiation of variables for the parent constructor. Otherwise if the `checkInit` boolean is false, then the parent constructor do nothing.
You can set this boolean variable in the child constructor pass him 'true' or 'false' if you want to initialize the variables through the parent constructor or no.